# Templates and overloadering operator <<

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to overload the << operator for a class template, but the compiler gives me a linker error. The goal is to be able to send a de-referenced base class pointer to std::cout so that the derived operator<< gets called.

Is this possible?

```
class IBase
{
public:
    IBase() {};
    virtual ~IBase() {};
};

template <typename T>
class Derived
    : public IBase
{
public:
    Derived(T data);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T>& dt);
private:
    T data_;
};

template <typename T>
Derived<T>::Derived(T data)
    : IBase(),
      data_(data)
{
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T>& dt)
{
    os << dt.data_;
    return os;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    // Question 1
    Derived<int> der(234);
    std::cout << der;

    // Question 2
    //IBase* base = new Derived<int>(5);
    // std::cout << *base
}
```

Here are the errors:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl
>   operator<<(class std::basic_ostream
>
> > &,class Derived const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$Derived@H@@@Z)

and

> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declarate friend operator as a template too

```
template<typename T1>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T1>& dt);
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick

Answer (score 2):

`friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T>& dt);`

declares a non template version `friend`, so you would have to implement

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T>& dt);
```

for every `T` you use:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<int>& dt) {
    return os << dt.data_;
}
```

And so on.
A way to do it without duplicate code is with definition inside the class:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public IBase
{
public:
    explicit Derived(T data);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T>& dt)
    {
        return os << dt.data_;
    }
private:
    T data_;
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ddT847)

An other alternative is to make the function template.

```
// Forward declarations
template <typename T> class Derived;
template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T>& dt);
```

And then in `Derived`, you have 2 choices:

- Declare each the template method friend:

  ```
  template <typename T2>
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T2>& dt);
  ```

  So `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<int>& dt)` has access to private members of `Derived<int>`, but also to the ones of `Derived<char>`

  [Demo](https://ideone.com/CoVp33)
- Declare only the template which matches the argument:

  ```
  friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& os, const Derived& dt);
  ```

  and so `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<int>& dt)` doesn't have access to private members of `Derived<char>`.

  [Demo](https://ideone.com/E3IYFD)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T>& dt);
```

with

```
template<typename D>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<D>& dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that the operator needs to be templated.

However, your ultimate goal can't be attained through templates alone as dereferencing a `IBase*` gets you a `IBase&` - template instantiation occurs at compile time and the compiler has no access to the runtime type.

So your templated operator will never be used if you pass a dereferenced `IBase*` to `operator <<`.

Instead, add a virtual output function to the base and override it:

```
class IBase
{
public:
    IBase() {};
    virtual ~IBase() {};
    virtual std::ostream& output(std::ostream&) const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived
    : public IBase
{
public:
    Derived(T data);
    virtual std::ostream& output(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        os << data;
        return os;
    }
private:
    T data_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const IBase& dt)
{
    return dt.output(os);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I asked this as a separate question a few minutes ago, please post your answer there so that I can accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496137/virtual-operator-and-templates

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make your `friend` a template:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T>& dt);
```

This needs to be changed to:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& os, const Derived<T>& dt);
```

The `operator<<` function will need to be visible before the `friend` declaration for this form to work.

You should prefer this form to making the `friend` a template because you don't need all of the operator's instantiations to be `friend`s, just one of them.